# Response Error form sql adapter in Biztalk 2013

Tags: sql-server, biztalk

I created a sql adapter to insert data into sql server 2008 using biztalk 2013.But I keep getting this error.When I put the file with my records into the folder,It will get inserted into sql,repeat the process and the file remains in the folder as a WIP file and is suspended.If I restart the biztalk service,and check sql server,my records are there.Not really sure what is causing this.

```
    Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'GMLSQLInsert_Final.Orchestration_1(53af03a7-0a27-d8cc-631f-8bbb55d960f3)'.
The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated. 
If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
InstanceId: 241a55bb-b5e4-499c-a495-477b973fad3f
Shape name: 
ShapeId: 
Exception thrown from: segment -1, progress -1
Inner exception: Received unexpected message type 'HTTP://InsertSQLData#MyResponse' does not match expected type 'http://InsertSQLData#MyResponse'.

Exception type: UnexpectedMessageTypeException
Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.Engine
Target Site: Void VerifyMessage(Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Envelope, System.String, Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Context, Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.OperationInfo)
The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured

   at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.PortBinding.VerifyM
```

This is the XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
- <xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:tns="http://InsertSQLData" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://InsertSQLData" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
- <xs:element name="MyRequest">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
- <xs:element xmlns:updategram="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-updategram" updategram:Prefix="updg" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="sync">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
- <xs:element updategram:Prefix="updg" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="after">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
- <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="testTable">
- <xs:complexType>
  <xs:attribute name="FirstName" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="Lastname" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="city" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="address" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="postalCode" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
- <xs:element name="MyResponse">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Success" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

Message in the response

```
<ns:MyResponse xmlns:ns="HTTP://InsertSQLData"><ns:Success /></ns:MyResponse>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That error is not from the WCF SQL Adapter.  That error is raised by the Orchestration Engine because the received Message Type does not match the one configured on the Port.

You need to find out why HTTP is CAPS in the response namespace.  There is no BizTalk component I'm aware of that will do that.